# JSoup error 403 when trying to read the contents of a directory on my website

Tags: directory, jsoup, http-status-code-403, virtual-directory

Exception in thread "main" org.jsoup.HttpStatusException: HTTP error fetching URL. Status=403, URL=(site)
    at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.execute(HttpConnection.java:449)
    at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.execute(HttpConnection.java:465)
    at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.execute(HttpConnection.java:424)
    at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection.execute(HttpConnection.java:178)
    at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection.get(HttpConnection.java:167)
    at plan.URLReader.main(URLReader.java:21)

Hello all!

I have been looking up a way to read a directory on a website of mine for an application I'm developing.

I can read the files themselves and work with them if I hardcode it, but if I try to grab the list of files from the directory I get this error.

I've tried a few ways, but this is the code I am currently working with.

String url = ""//(removed site for privacy);
        print("Fetching %s...", url);

```
    Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/35.0.1916.153 Safari/537.36").get();
    Elements links = doc.select("a[href]");
    Elements media = doc.select("[src]");
    Elements imports = doc.select("link[href]");
```

...
...
...

Now if I use the main site as in www.google.com/ it reads the links.  The problem is I want a directory as in www.google.com/something/something/...

when I try that for my site I am getting this error.

Any idea why I can access my main site, but not directories within it?

I also notice that '/' is needed at the end.

Just curious if am I missing something, or need to do something another way?

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is likely a problem with (or deliberate attempt to block access using) the server's configuration, not your application.  From the tag wiki excerpt for the http-status-code-403 tag:

> The 403 or "Forbidden" error message is a HTTP standard response code indicating that the request was legal and understood but the server refuses to respond to the request.

From the [tag wiki itself](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/http-status-code-403/info):

> A 403 Forbidden may be returned by a web server due to an authorization issue or other constraint related to the request. File permissions, lack of encryption, and maximum number of users reached (among others) can all be the cause of a 403 response.

If the target site is attempting to block screen-scraping, another possibility is an unrecognized user-agent string, but you're setting the user-agent string to one (I presume) you've obtained from an actual browser, so that shouldn't be the cause.

It's not clear from your question if you expect to fetch a regular (HTML) web page, or a special "directory listing" page generated by the server when an index.html is not present in a directory.  If it's the latter, note that many servers have these listings disabled to avoid leaking the names of files in the directory that aren't linked to from the web site itself.  Again, this is a server configuration issue, not something your application can work around.

Comment: Thank you very much for that.

So I can read the files fine and the server has no problem with it, but I cannot look at the directory?

I try to look at it via the web I do get an error as well.


Server Error in Application "WEB SITE"
Internet Information Services 7.5
Error Summary
HTTP Error 403.14 - Forbidden
The Web server is configured to not list the contents of this directory.
Detailed Error Information
Module DirectoryListingModule
Notification ExecuteRequestHandler
Handler StaticFile
Error Code 0x00000000
Requested URL 
Physical Path 
Logon Method Anonymous
Logon User Anonymous

Comment: Yes.  It's right there in the response: "The Web server is configured to not list the contents of this directory."  And as your browser gets that response, your Jsoup application will as well.

Comment: Sorry didn't mean to ask a question there, when I posted teh answer haha....

It then has a list of "most likely causes."

Now I don't know much about server configurations (I could look that all up) but is there a way for me to access it without allowing others to do the same via the browser, or how I'm doing?

It seems that it's accessed as "Anonymous" so I'm curious if there is a way for me to login first or something???

Thanks again for the help!

Comment: I also get this

If you do not want to enable directory browsing, ensure that a default document is configured and that the file exists.
Enable directory browsing using IIS Manager.
Open IIS Manager.
In the Features view, double-click Directory Browsing.
On the Directory Browsing page, in the Actions pane, click Enable.
Verify that the configuration/system.webServer/directoryBrowse@enabled attribute is set to true in the site or application configuration file.

It seems if I do this then it will be open to everyone, but it might not be a huge deal as no one would really know where the path is.

Comment: You could use HTTP Basic Authentication (low security but simple to configure), or SSL/TLS client certificate authentication (high security but also high effort to implement).  How to configure your server to use those are their own questions, possibly better suited for (or already asked!) on Server Fault or Webmasters.SE than here on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Hmm for some reason my last post didn't go through...

I said I am in the process of configuring an Apache Shiro authentication for my application so I will check out about that and configuring the server(I'm assuming I would do it with that like you mentioned with the above methods)?

I will also check out those sites, thank you again for your time, and help.

Answer (score 2):

```
String mylink = "http://www.imdb.com/search/title?genres=action";

Connection connection = Jsoup.connect(mylink);
connection.userAgent("Mozilla/5.0");
Document doc = connection.get();

//Elements elements = doc.body().select("tr.even detailed");
Elements elements = doc.getElementsByClass("results");

System.out.println(elements.toString());
```

Answer (score 0):

One of the possible reason is don't have access from Java code to access external websites use proxy to connect.

```
System.setProperty("http.proxyHost", "<<proxy host>>"); 
System.setProperty("http.proxyPort", "<<proxy port>>");
```